# Work trip to two Australian clients - letters of invitation and visa extension

Tags: australia, italy, covid-19, visa-extensions, working-visas

My friend is an Italian specialist who travels quite often for work; in April he'll have to go to Australia to fix a problem for Client A.

The client has sent him a Letter of Invitation that will allow him to apply for a work visa for the whole month.

Due to Covid restrictions, he'll have to quarantine for half of that time; this was accounted for, the problem of Client A can be fixed in the remaining time.

Now Client B, also Australian, wants to hire my friend for a couple of weeks in May.

A and B are not direct competitors, but A is not in the mood of doing any free favours to B, so they won't extend their Letter of Invitation to cover May too.

My friend can get a Letter of Invitation from B for the two weeks in May, but such a letter will include the date of entry - what would that date be? By the time the invitation from Client B comes into effect, he will have been in Australia for a full month!

Can Client B somehow extend the invitation of Client A, even if the two firms are not on speaking terms? Is there some other solution that does not involve exiting the country and doing another quarantine?

Comment: Can't the friend include a bit of vacation in a working visit, and supply both invitations to justify a single visa for 2 months? The schedule would be quarantine, job one, vacation, job two. Surely it's not unusual to visit several unconnected clients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your friend will likely be applying for the Subclass 400
Temporary Work (Short Stay) visa:

https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/temporary-work-400

As far as I can tell, there is no restriction that limits them to a single employer, so I would submit the application with *both* Letters of Invitation attached and request a period of stay covering both jobs.  If granted, they are free to travel Australia for tourism etc between jobs:

> Combining a holiday with your intended work or activity may be allowed if the holiday is of short term duration and secondary to the main purpose of your visit.